# how to query a repeated property at a specific index?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to store hierarchical labels to my data in a repeated property.
E.g.
['Label', 'Sublabel', 'Sublabel2', ...]

I would then like to query entity (sub)groups by 'Label', or 'Label' + 'Sublabel', or 'Label' + 'Sublabel' + 'Sublabel2', etc.

Is there a way to query a repeated property at a certain index?

The examples I have found only show querying using the IN operator:

```
Article.tags.IN(['python', 'ruby', 'php'])
```

But I would like to do something like:

```
Article.query(Article.tags[0]=='python', Article.tags[1]=='ruby', Article.tags[2]=='php')
```

I would like to avoid using ancestors for performance reasons.

I suppose I could use AND if the each sub(label) is unique across positions in the repeated property.
E.g.

```
Article.tags.query(ndb.AND(Article.tags == 'python',
                             Something.tags == 'ruby'))
```

In that case, would queries be slow?

Comment: I found another approach.  I can store the labels in a single string.  

E.g.
Label/Sublabel/Sublabel2

Then I can use prefix matching to find data by Label, or Label/Sublabel, or etc.

E.g. something like this:

      filter WHERE labels > "id1/" and labels < "id1/" + u"\ufffd"

where u"\ufffd" represents the largest possible Unicode character

Comment: Yes, if as it appears order if meaningful for you, then it's not a good use case for a repeated property -- your joint-string approach is good (of course you'll have the usual limit of 1500 bytes on the max length of an indexed property).